# ImportingConstructor MEF with Caliburn Micro in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mef, caliburn.micro

Quick question, I have a couple of viewmodels that get assigned in the ShellViewModel (Export has been used for those 3 VMs)

```
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ShellViewModel(MainWindowViewModel viewModel,
                          SelectionViewModel sViewModel,
                          GStatsViewModel gsViewModel)
    {
        mainWindowViewModel = viewModel;
        selectionViewModel = sViewModel;
        gStatsViewModel = gsViewModel;
    }
```

Question is, I wanted to Inject a "Service" into the MainWindowViewModel.

This is the Service

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
[Export(typeof(IObjService))]
public class ObjService : IObjService
{
    private ObservableCollection<ObjA> objSource = new ObservableCollection<ObjA>();
    public ObservableCollection<ObjA> ObjSource
    {
        get { return objSource; }
        set
        {
            objSource= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And in my MainWindowViewModel

```
    private ObjService objService;

    // Can I use the importing constructor here?
    public MainWindowViewModel(// something here?)
    {
        // Setup service
        // or something here?
```

Question is, how can I do this? How can MainWindowViewModel have an importing constructor but work the way it does at the moment how I have it in the ShellViewModel?

Also, is this ok? I want viewmodels to always have the same reference of observable collection of ObjA as this is going to be used globally.... so is this the way to go forward?

Thanks

My app is using the MVVM architecture

**EDIT**

if I do this

```
    private ObjService objService;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainWindowViewModel(ObjService serviceToUse)
    {
        // Setup service
        objService = serviceToUse;
```

i get an exception from Caliburn Micro saying

```
throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
```

For IShell

In the bootstrapper I do

```
        var batch = new CompositionBatch();

        batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
        batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
        batch.AddExportedValue<IObjService>(new ObjService());
        batch.AddExportedValue(container);

        container.Compose(batch);
```

If I change the constructor to this in the MainWindowViewModel, it works... I'm not sure why it works with an interface but not the concrete class. I think this is because it gets translated to a new concrete class anyway so you should be giving it the interface, correct?

The part that works
        private IObjService objService;

```
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainWindowViewModel(IObjService serviceToUse)
    {
        // Setup service
        objService = serviceToUse;
```

Comment: Since you export `IObjService`, you should import `IObjService` in your viewmodel's constructor and mark that constructor with the `[ImportingConstructor]` attribute. What exactly is not clear to you?

Comment: Hey dymanoid. Question is do I have to change anything in the ShellViewModel is all

Comment: @dymanoid see edit...

Comment: Yep - just did... sorry! still the morning... Can you read my edit? Just confirm my thinking is correct... also, as mentioned about the observable collection being global, is this ok? Can other viewmodels be injected with my IObjService and the collection they use is essentially the same "reference"?

Comment: The answer to your last question is still in my first comment...

Comment: Since you export IObjService, you should import IObjService in your viewmodel's constructor and mark that constructor with the [ImportingConstructor] attribute. 

that's your answer to "Can other viewmodels be injected with my IObjService and the collection they use is essentially the same "reference"?" yeah? Sorry I'm wanting to be very certain of this that's all...... I don't want it biting me in the backside that it's going to be another "instance" or something but it wouldn't make sense to be... so it's definitely going to be a single point of reference i reckon...

Comment: Ok, I understand that thank you... but I'm saying about the comment I made about it being the same "reference". Can you confirm that is the case? Just so I can confirm my understanding is correct.

Comment: @dymanoid do you know?